# не открывается сайт Джанго, подключенный к домену

Tags: python, django, ssh

Мой сайт лежит в хостинге и подключен к домену, но каждый раз при заходе на сайт говорит, что отсутствует индексный файл, а я не могу его вытащить из папки, иначе все собьется. Как я могу заходит на сайт через домен по `manage.py`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

wsgi.py:

```py
"""
WSGI config for Logist project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os, sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/u2025771/data/www/gruzivizi.ru/Logist')
sys.path.insert(1, '/var/www/u2025771/data/djangoenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages')

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Logist.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Читайте о правильном подключении Django в документации используемого вами хостинга

Comment: А ещё не забывайте, что при таком способе подключения абсолютно любой пользователь может скачать всю вашу базу данных, вытащить оттуда сессионные ключи, войти в вашу админку как суперпользователь и возможно даже узнать пароли